# Python: partially initialize instance

Tags: python

Not sure wether it is possible or not in general but i have a following question:

for example we have class Foo

```py
class Foo:
   def __init__(a, b, c):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b
       self.c = c

   def sum(self):
       return self.a + self.b + self.c
```

What i want to do is to get somehow partially initialized instance of this class with **a**, **b** initialized and possibility to initialize **c** later.

```py
# pseudocode

partially_initialized = something(Foo, a=1, b=2)
fully_initialized = partially_initialized(c=3)
fully_initialized.sum() -> 6
```

python version 3.6

Comment: Just don't put `self.c = c` in `__init__`. It's not a good idea though, partially initialised objects are very prone to AttributeErrors.

Comment: Another possibility is to use `functools.partial` to create a function with only some of the arguments applied, but this will not give you the actual instance until you provide all the attributes.

Comment: `partial`, in some sense, provides an implementation of the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).